# What are the differences between the question and answer follow buttons?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, follow-post

I just realized that the original question has a clickable follow button and also if someone answers a question that has a clickable follow button.

If I want to follow the original question, I understand following it so I can get edits, comments answers etc. What's up with the follow Clickable follow button under the answer? won't the follow under the question give me all activity regardless of what happens?

Comment: I believe following a question will notify you if a new answer is posted to a question, but it won't notify you about any other interactions to the answers (such as answers being edited or comments to answers). If you want notifications for interactions to answers, you have to follow individual answers.

Comment: So @CaveJohnson following a question and following an answer are two different things? I know when I follow a question I get notification's of comments answers and edits

Comment: Yes I believe so. When you say you get notifications of comments and edits, I think those are only on the question itself right? You don't get notifications for comments and edits on answers (unless you follow them as I mentioned).

Comment: Got it. @CaveJohnson Can you write that in an answer so I can get you some rep like you need anymore :P

Comment: I just opted to vote to close as duplicate. That question more-or-less says what I said.

Comment: Thanks @CaveJohnson it was the first hit after I did a site:stackexchange.com follow question and answer